# 2. Let $E =\{(x,y,z) ∈\mathbb{ R}^{3} | x,y,z > 0,xy + yz + zx = 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

2. Let $E = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} | x,y,z > 0,xy + yz + zx = 1\}$. Prove that there exists $(a,b,c) \in E$ such that $abc ≥ xyz$, for all $(x,y,z) \in E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  by [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) $\;\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2} \le \dfrac{xy+yz+zx}{3}=\dfrac{1}{3}\;$ so $\;xyz \le \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3^3}}\,$, with equality iff $\,x=y=z\,$.

Comment: Please explain the only if part: Why $xyz = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3^3}}$ holds only if $x=y=z$?

Comment: Also, can I prove it by using [Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_theorem)? I know that $E$ not compact, but can we restrict $E$ so that it becomes bounded, as well as max lies in that bounded region only? Thanks.

Comment: @Silent The equality case of AM-GM is when all terms are equal, in this case $xy=yz=zx$, which in strictly positive numbers implies $x=y=z$.

Comment: @Silent Using calculus to solve it is possible (with some care), though it would be a bit of an overkill here IMHO.

Comment: Thank you very much.